# Add secondary y axis

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I have two graphs:
[image]
[image]

That I combined into one:
[image]

Here's my code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                  'b': [3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5],
                  'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                  'd': [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]}, 
                  index=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Jan': [100,50,1/3*100,25,20,1/6*100,1/7*100,1/8*100,1/9*100,10],
                   'Feb': [0,50,1/3*100,25,20,1/6*100,1/7*100,1/8*100,1/9*100,10],
                   'Mar': [0,0,1/3*100,25,20,1/6*100,1/7*100,1/8*100,1/9*100,10],
                   'Apr': [0,0,0,25,20,1/6*100,1/7*100,1/8*100,1/9*100,10],
                   'May': [0,0,0,0,20,1/6*100,1/7*100,1/8*100,1/9*100,10],
                   'Jun': [0,0,0,0,0,1/6*100,1/7*100,1/8*100,1/9*100,10],
                   'Jul': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1/7*100,1/8*100,1/9*100,10],
                   'Aug': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1/8*100,1/9*100,10],
                   'Sep': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1/9*100,10],
                   'Oct': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10]},
                  index=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct'])

ax = df.a.plot.line()
ax2 = df2.plot.bar(stacked=True)
df.a.plot.line(ax=ax2,secondary_y=range(0,11))
```

I want to have a secondary y axis on the combined graph from 0-10 so that the line in the combined graph is scaled to what it is when it's plotted by itself. I tried to use the `secondary_y` field but looks like I didn't use it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`ax.twinx()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html):

```
df.a.plot.line(ax=ax.twinx(), secondary_y=range(0, 11))
```

Instead of:

```
df.a.plot.line(ax=ax,secondary_y=range(0,11))
```

**Full example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                   'b': [3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5],
                   'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   'd': [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]},
                  index=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Jan': [100, 50, 1/3*100, 25, 20, 1/6*100, 1/7*100, 1/8*100, 1/9*100, 10],
                    'Feb': [0, 50, 1/3*100, 25, 20, 1/6*100, 1/7*100, 1/8*100, 1/9*100, 10],
                    'Mar': [0, 0, 1/3*100, 25, 20, 1/6*100, 1/7*100, 1/8*100, 1/9*100, 10],
                    'Apr': [0, 0, 0, 25, 20, 1/6*100, 1/7*100, 1/8*100, 1/9*100, 10],
                    'May': [0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 1/6*100, 1/7*100, 1/8*100, 1/9*100, 10],
                    'Jun': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/6*100, 1/7*100, 1/8*100, 1/9*100, 10],
                    'Jul': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/7*100, 1/8*100, 1/9*100, 10],
                    'Aug': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/8*100, 1/9*100, 10],
                    'Sep': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/9*100, 10],
                    'Oct': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]},
                   index=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct'])


# Get axis
f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = f.add_subplot(111)


df.a.plot.line(ax=ax, secondary_y=range(0, 11))
df2.plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax.twinx())

ax.set_zorder(ax.twinx().get_zorder()+1)    # update zorder
ax.patch.set_visible(False)                 # hide the 'canvas'

# Fix size border bars
plt.autoscale(tight=True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just some housekeeping stuff, how could I swap the y axes? So 0-10 on the left and 0-100 on the right? Also, Jan and Oct are cut off, anyway to fix that?

Comment: Sorry for being picky, is there a way to have the line overlap the bars rather than bars overlapping the line?

Comment: @cap `zorder` do the trick with `patch.set_visible` to `false` for the top layer. I let you finetune it for the legend. The answer is updated ! Some [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in matplotlib.pyplot by using `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` and then plotting your stacked bar chart on ax2.